# How to database iOS app data and display it on a webpage

Tags: mysql, ios, database, web-services, backend

First time post here, so forgive me for any bad etiquette/format.

I will preface by saying:

I have (over the last few months) been developing an iOS app for work.  To be more specific, I am developing an inventory app to track bar inventory (liquor, beer, wine, etc).  I can give more specifics on request if needed.  I have most of the functionality done, only a couple more things I would like to implement.  Eventually I will be porting it to Android as well.

At the moment, I have the model objects being archived to the local filesystem for saving and loading of data.  However, my goal would be to database the model objects with the ability to display the information on a webpage.  My logic is that no matter where the user is, he/she will be able to sign in to a service using a username and password, and view correctly formatted current/past inventories online.  This is to allow the ability for a bartender to record the inventory, and have the bar manager view the inventory instances without having to have the physical device that recorded the inventory in his/her possession.

So here is my question:

Without being too general, what kind of service would I need to pull this off?  I have a good amount of relevant front-end experience, specifically with iOS, Objective-C, HTML and CSS.  However, I have ZERO experience on the back-end.  I have researched around the internet, and I am aware of things such as cloud databases, web hosting and MySQL, etc.  However, I cannot seem to find a definitive answer without asking my specific question.  I suppose I would just like to be pointed in the right direction before investing money and time into a service that may prove useless to my cause.

Any resources and help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: You have tons of options, but basically you need a server, some sort of SQL database (mysql, postgresql...), pick a scripting language (php, perl, Java, Javascript...), and write a script to store and retrieve the data. Which one you pick is really up to you, there's really no good or bad choice.

Comment: Okay perfect, thank you. So the obvious first step would be to sign up for web hosting?

Comment: I think the first step is to pick a language. There are specialised hosting providers for some solutions that will make the deployment much quicker and easier.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a definitive answer and you have a lot of options.

For me, the simplest is to set up a server with a database incorporated (mysql for example) and with a web service (written in PHP for example) that manages the database and queries on that.

Online you can find tons of guide on how to write a script in PHP that manages a database:
http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/2

For the iOS part you can follow also this guide:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-your-own-web-service-for-an-ios-app-part-one/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the push in the right direction. I'm starting to see here that there are a lot of options. Probably the reason I couldn't find a good one in my search. I believe I actually ran across that tech republic blog post earlier, but I wasn't sure if it was what I needed, so thank you for the links.